# DAO withdrawal contract - executed but no ethers

Tags: ether, the-dao, internal-transactions

Yesterday I executed the DAO Withdrawal Contract. Everything seemed to work, all the transactions were confirmed. However, the ether did not return to my ether wallet. Apparently the transaction was listed as an "internal transaction" and I am not sure where my ethers are now. Hopefully somebody knows what went wrong and how I can fix it?

This is the TXhash: 0x073d5f9576d5971fd544e401f47c23bba47178890c1449887aa325ac88fff4e2
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x073d5f9576d5971fd544e401f47c23bba47178890c1449887aa325ac88fff4e2

Comment: Already have a solution? I've got the same problem now. Will appreciate your help :)

Comment: the TX hash you specified above is few months old, do you have a recent one (you mentioned yesterday in your post).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the transaction is *supposed* to be listed as an internal transaction. It looks like you accidentally sent 385 *new* ether to the withdrawal contract and that you figured out you only need to provide your TheDao balance to the contract, not actually send any new Eth.